# How to cast from Obj[ , ] to Obj[ ]

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

In my C# project I need from `Tile[ , ]` make `Tile[ ]` to iterate in one row.

```
Tile[,] tiles = playfield.Tiles;
Tile[] center_row = Tile[row / 2]; // does not work
```

Do I need from `Tile[ , ]` make `Tile[ ][ ]` or it is a way to directly convert it?

**Update**

My problem was solved with help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32903582/12416559
answer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please share with us how do you store data inside the `tiles` (like `[column, row]` or `[row, column]`)?

Comment: If you want to avoid copying elements to a new array, then using a `Tile[ ][ ]` is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BlockCopy` to move all the data from one form to another.

### In Theory

Here is a solution as extension methods

```
    public static T[] MatrixToVector<T>(this T[,] matrix)
    {
        var size = Buffer.ByteLength(matrix);
        var vector = new T[matrix.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(matrix, 0, vector, 0, size);
        return vector;
    }
    public static T[,] VectorToMatrix<T>(this T[] vector, int rows, int columns)
    {
        var size = Buffer.ByteLength(vector);
        var matrix = new T[rows,columns];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(vector, 0, matrix, 0, size);
        return matrix;
    }
```

### In Practice

The array can only be of primitive types

[image: fig2]

### Casting to the rescue

StackOverflow to the rescue [with a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32903582/380384)

```
    public static T[] MatrixToVector<T>(this T[,] matrix)
    {
        var vector = matrix.Cast<T>().ToArray();
        return vector;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You into UnityEngine, I get it? :)

Ok so you can use the Buffer.BlockCopy Method like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322479/converting-2-dimensional-array-to-single-dimensional-in-c)

Comment: If another question's answers answer this question, please flag this question as a duplicate of that other question, rather than answering with a link and no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If iteration is what you want, then you can get `IEnumerator` from it and simply iterate through:

```
int[,] res = new int[2, 2]
    {
        {1,2 },
        {33,45 }
    };

var enumerator = res.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```